# Apache httpd: Conditionally run a program if a specific *response* header is set

Tags: apache, http-headers, httpd.conf

I need to configure httpd 2.2 for filtering responses under certain conditions. I can filter responses using external scripts with [mod_ext_filter](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html), but I'd like to trigger the filter only if a specfic response-header is set. How can I achieve this?

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding but... Headers are set "after" requests have been made, and scripts are ran when requests are being made. Can you clarify further?

Comment: you can use SetOutputFilter for filtering responses. Using mod_ext_filter you can filter responses using an external script, i need something like <if reponse header "myheader" is set>SetOutputFilter myfilter</if>